# PHPMailer get addresses from file

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, mailer

I'm trying to **get addresses from a simple text file**, so people who don't understand code can still add/remove or change the adresses.

**Phpmailer is working totally fine when I set up an address normally**, writing it directly in the code, and even with an array and a foreach.

So at the moment I have this :

**mail.php :**

```
//all phpmailer settings on $mail var
$addresses = file('mail.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($addresses as $email) {
    echo "$email<br>";
    $mail->addAddress($email);
}
```

**mail.txt :**

```
'first@address.com'
'second@address.fr'
```

The **echo does return both addresses** but the var doesn't seem to work in the addAddress() line, and I get the usual error :
Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.

Thanks for correcting me if I'm wrong or if you know any other solution that could work !

---

---

Okay so here is the working code corrected with the help of Waqas Shahid :

**mail.php :**

```
//all phpmailer settings on $mail var
$addresses = file('mail.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($addresses as $email) {
    $email = trim($email);
    $change = array('\n', '\t', '\r');
    $email = str_replace($change, "", $email);
    $mail->addAddress($email);
}
```

**mail.txt :**

```
first@address.com
second@address.fr
```

Comment: remove single quote from file and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove single quotes first, then get value line by line and remove whitespaces using `trim()` then remove '\n', '\t', '\r' using `str_replace()`

Comment: Well that was quick, simple, and it worked haha. Thanks ! I'm editing my question with the correct code.